# Automatically authenticate a user if they exist in an email distribution list?

Tags: asp.net

I have an asp.net web application. I want to auto log in a user based on whether the user is in a email distribution list. Is it possible? If not what’s the best way to go about this?

Thanks :)

Comment: How do you intend to identify the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't be able to do the auto login, however one possible route to explore is if you're email distro groups are stored within an active directory you may possibly be able to get the users within the group by doing forms authentication via ldap against your active directory...

here is a reference on doing ldap authentication. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649227.aspx

also when i was doing ldap auth i found this tool to be a godsend 
http://www.ldapbrowser.com/

Hopefully this helps!